# Windows 10 dual boot won't boot to GRUB (boot error url)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have been having issues trying to get my dual boot to work. Specifically, windows won't boot to GRUB. Even after the first restart my computer didn't boot into GRUB In addition, I have tried to boot ubuntu using the normal boot manager. I go "Boot From EFI File" -> a very long set of characters -> EFI -> ubuntu and the error reads "No valid file selected in the selected file system".

I am running Windows 10 on an HP Specter and trying to boot into Ubuntu 20.04.

I have tried many things like changing the boot order, however there is no windows or Ubuntu option to choose from.
I have disabled secure boot.
I have redownloaded Ubuntu several times.

I just ran the boot repair and it gave this url: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zM7xdDPjvd/
and was told to post it on the forums for help.

Thank you for any help, I have been struggling with this for weeks.

Comment: Most HP: HP - escape + F9 for boot menu, F10 for bios setup. Have you updated UEFI from HP? And updated SSD firmware? Most with HP have said they have to set boot order in UEFI set up f10 (not boot menu).  Is this an X360? HP X360 Update UEFI F20
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220 [Guide] Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Spectre x360 13" 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422113

Answer (score 0):

Next time you start your computer up, spam f9 and you should see a screen offering some options to boot from. Select ubuntu.

If you don't want to do this every time, enter the BIOS menu with f12. Navigate to the boot options tab and change the boot order (not legacy boot) to ubuntu first. It will look something like [this](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-boot-order-in-bios-2624528) tutorial but instead of +/- its f5 and f6. Make sure to hit f10 when changing the boot order to save changes. Reboot.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I open the menu with f9 and navigate to ubuntu I get this error "No valid file selected in the selected file system".